# How to get program I made to loop back to another part?

Tags: python-2.7, loops

Sorry if this question is considered a "duplicate" but I couldn't find any answers relevant to what I'm asking. So, my question sounds very complicated, so I'll just show you the code I wrote and what I want it to do. Here is the code:

```
    def area_of_circle(c):
    if float(c) > 0 and type(float(c)) == int or float:
        return float(c) ** 2 * 3.14
    else:
        return "Needs to be positive"

def length(l):
    if float(l) > 0 and float(l) == float or int:
        return l

def height(h):
    if float(h) > 0 and float(h) == float or int:
        return h

def area_of_rectangle(length, height):
    if float(l) > 0 and float(l) == int or float and float(h) > 0 and float(h) == float or int:
        return float(l) * float(h)
    else:
        return "Needs to be positive"

def area_of_square(a):
    if float(a) > 0 and type(float(a)) == int or float:
        return float(a) ** 2
    else:
        return "Needs to be positive"

user_reply = raw_input("Find the area of different shapes! Type circle, square, or rectangle!")
if user_reply == 'circle' or user_reply == 'Circle':
    c = raw_input('You chose circle! What is the radius?')
    print "The area of the cirlce would be", area_of_circle(c)
elif user_reply == 'Square' or user_reply == 'square':
    a = raw_input('You chose square! What is the length of one side?')
    print "The area of the square would be", area_of_square(a)
elif user_reply == 'Rectangle' or user_reply == 'rectangle':
    l = raw_input('You chose rectangle! What is the length?')
    h = raw_input('What is the height?')
    print "The area of the rectangle would be", area_of_rectangle(l, h)
else:
    print 'That is not a valid response!'
    user_reply = raw_input("Cirlce, square, or rectangle?")
```

Ok so obviously this code I made basically tell you the area of either a square, rectangle, or circle based on the input it receives. It does everything it is supposed to correctly, but I want to know how I can make it so that at the end of my code where it says "Find the area of different shapes! Type circle, square, or rectangle!" if the person so happens to enter a different word and it takes them to the else statement where it prints "That is not a valid response", how would i make it so the program would take the user back to the part where it says "Find the area of different shapes! type circle, square, or rectangle!". Sorry about all the words and thank you to whoever took the time to read this!

Comment: Thanks so much it works better now, thanks also for pointing out the bugs! I'm definetly going to do more research on control flow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [While Loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) (or a [For Loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop))

```
while True:
    user_reply = raw_input("Find the area of different shapes! Type circle, square, or rectangle!")
    if user_reply == 'circle' or user_reply == 'Circle':
        ...
    elif user_reply == 'exit':
        break 
    else:
        print 'That is not a valid response!'
        user_reply = raw_input("Cirlce, square, or rectangle?")
```

More on control flow [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Also there are lots of bugs in your code, `float(c) > 0 and type(float(c)) == int or float:` will always return true because

- `float(c) > 0`, could be True or False, but can throw a exception if c is a string
- `type(float(c)) == int or float`, there are 2 statements

  - `type(float(c)) == int`, that will always be `False`, because you cast it as float and you are comparing to a `int`
  - `float`, this will always be `True`

If you want to check if a variables is an instance of a type you should use the function `isinstance(obj, class)` in your if statement.